# Update Jupyter to Python 3.4 in default Tensorflow docker container

Tags: python-3.x, docker, tensorflow, jupyter

I am using gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow docker image and need to update jupyter to python version 3.4 within the container. I've tried searching online but haven't really found how to do this. Could someone help me with this by explaining step-by-step?

Comment: https://github.com/himaprasoon/tensorflow-docker just modify the basedocker image to include jupyter

Answer (score 0):

There are now python3 builds available in the nightly docker images as of [pull 6030](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/6030).  See the [TensorFlow public docker repository](https://hub.docker.com/r/tensorflow/tensorflow/tags/)
 for a list of all docker images.